# Sed replace space with backslash space (Bash)

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying to replace every space in this text file with a backslash space.

```
cat prefixedfiles.txt | sed "s![[:space:]]! \!g"
```

Original:
`A a a`

Result:
   `A\ a\ a`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed 's! !\\ !g' prefixedfiles.txt
```

Few issues that are fixed:

- `'` instead of `"` prevents `bash` interpreting `!` symbol and allows referring to backslash as `\\`;
- `[[:space:]]` matches more than just space; you may want it or not, I used the regular space;
- `cat` is superfluous here; `sed` can take file name as an argument (and even if it couldn't, the syntax `sed < file.txt` is still better than `cat file.txt | sed`).

Answer (score 0):

Escape the backslash character.

```
cat prefixedfiles.txt | sed "s![[:space:]]! \\!g"
```

> [sed manual 5.3 Overview of basic regular expression syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Overview-of-basic-regular-expression-syntax)
>
> \char 
>   Matches *char*, where *char* is one of $, *, ., [, \, or ^. Note
>   that the only C-like backslash sequences that you can portably assume
>   to be interpreted are `\n` and `\\`; in particular `\t` is not portable, and
>   matches a ‘t’ under most implementations of sed, rather than a tab
>   character.